# How to test void method with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, void, ts-mockito

I would like to test if a logger increments correctly (using Jest). Looking at the code below this means I would like check if the increment `(1)` (meaning the content of the void `myMethod`) is getting called.

```
// myScript.ts
import dd from 'datadog-metrics';

export class MyClass { 
    private bufferedMetricsLogger: dd.BufferedMetricsLogger; 

    constructor(bufferedMetricsLogger: dd.BufferedMetricsLogger) { 
        this.bufferedMetricsLogger = bufferedMetricsLogger; 
    } 

    public myMethod(myInput: String): void { 
        this.bufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, [`myTag:${myInput}`]);  // (1)
    }
}

// myScript.test.ts
import { mock, instance, verify } from 'ts-mockito'; 
import { BufferedMetricsLogger } from 'datadog-metrics'; 
import { myClass } from 'path/to/myScript'; 

describe('Testing MyClass', () => { 
    it('verify that myMethod increments', () => { 
        const mockedBufferedMetricsLogger: BufferedMetricsLogger = mock(BufferedMetricsLogger); 
        const bufferedMetricsLogger:       BufferedMetricsLogger = instance(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger); 

        const mockMyClass: MyClass    = mock(MyClass); 
        const myClassOption1: MyClass = instance(mockMyClass); 
        const myClassOption2: MyClass = new MyClass(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger); 

        myClassOption1.myMethod('XXX');                                       // Option 1
        myClassOption2.myMethod('XXX');                                       // Option 2
        bufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, [`myTag:${XXX}`]);  // Option 3
        verify(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, [`myTag:${XXX}`])).once();
    })
});
```

I tried three different `Option`s. Every `Option` results in the message

```
Expected "increment(strictEqual(my.key.name)", strictEqual(1), strichtEqual([myTag:XXX]))" to be called 1 time(s). But has been called 0 time(s).
```

Actually either `Option 1` or `Option 2` is what I want. For `Option 3` I just tried it cause I thought this would definitely work.

Could somebody help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are passing an array as the third argument, and, as you can see in the returned message, it is trying to check it with an strictEqual (===). You can get the desired result using the `deepEqual` function provided by mockito.

```
verify(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, deepEqual([`myTag:${XXX}`]))).once();
```

And be sure you are dealing with the parameters correctly, as I had to change the code a bit to make it work. Here's my full working code:

```
// myScript.ts
import { BufferedMetricsLogger } from 'datadog-metrics';

export class MyClass { 
    private bufferedMetricsLogger: BufferedMetricsLogger; 

    constructor(bufferedMetricsLogger: BufferedMetricsLogger) { 
        this.bufferedMetricsLogger = bufferedMetricsLogger; 
    } 

    public myMethod(myInput: String): void {
        this.bufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, [`myTag:${myInput}`]);  // (1)
    }
}


// myScript.test.ts
import { mock, instance, verify, deepEqual } from 'ts-mockito'; 
import { BufferedMetricsLogger } from 'datadog-metrics'; 
import { MyClass } from './myScript'; 

describe('Testing MyClass', () => { 
    it('verify that myMethod increments', () => { 
        const mockedBufferedMetricsLogger: BufferedMetricsLogger = mock(BufferedMetricsLogger);
        const bufferedMetricsLogger:       BufferedMetricsLogger = instance(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger); 

        const myClassOption1 = new MyClass(bufferedMetricsLogger);
        // const bufferedMetricsLogger:       BufferedMetricsLogger = instance(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger); 

        // const mockMyClass: MyClass    = mock(MyClass); 
        // const myClassOption1: MyClass = instance(mockMyClass); 
        // const myClassOption2: MyClass = new MyClass(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger); 

        myClassOption1.myMethod('XXX');                                       // Option 1
        // myClassOption2.myMethod('XXX');                                       // Option 2
        // bufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, [`myTag:XXX`]);  // Option 3
        verify(mockedBufferedMetricsLogger.increment('my.key.name', 1, deepEqual([`myTag:XXX`]))).once();
    })
});
```